# Call Module in Other Class

Tags: python, class, module

So I have a close() method that is called when the user clicks the close button.  The close method is as follows:

```
def close(self):
    ThreadedClient.endApplication()

    root.destroy()
```

The close() method is inside a GUI() class.  The close method needs to call the endApplication() method in the ThreadedClient class.  But instead it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: unbound method endApplication() must be called with ThreadedClient instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

This may be a simple solution, but I just don't know how to fix it.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The question you need to be asking is *which* `ThreadedClient` needs to have `.endApplication()` called on it.

Once you have a reference to it (assuming you store a reference in `self`)

```
def close(self):
    self.threaded_client.endApplication()
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `endApplication()` is an instance method, but `ThreadedClient` is a *class*. You need to provide it with the actual instance of `ThreadedClient` that you want to end.

For instance, if somewhere else you created a threaded client with...

```
foo = ThreadedClient()
```

then later on you'd need to call...

```
foo.endApplication()
```